# How can I allow only 0 or 1 to be entered in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, textbox

How can I limit the TextBox control to only allow the values 0 and 1?

Thanks. And I have one more question: How can I disable put text from clipboard in my textbox control?

Comment: I would be interested to know your answer to Sean's question, as I frankly can't think of a use case my self.

Comment: I presumed he was asking the user for a binary string, eg. 1001001

Comment: 01010111 01101000 01100001 01110100 00100000 01101001 01100110 00100000 01111001 01101111 01110101 00100000 01110111 01100001 01101110 01110100 00100000 01110100 01101111 00100000 01100100 01101111 00100000 01110100 01101000 01101001 01110011 00111111

Comment: "What if you want to do this?" - Well that'd be a perfect case.

Comment: I don't know about GenericTypeTea, but I used LeetKey -- a lovely add-on for Firefox.  :-)

Comment: 01010111 01101000 01100101 01100101 00100001 00100000 01001111 01101110 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100001 01101110 01100100 00100000 01011010 01100101 01110010 01101111 01110011 00100000 01100111 01100001 01101100 01101111 01110010 01100101 00100001 00100000 00111010 00101101 00101001

Answer (score 12):

By using the event `KeyPress`

```
private void NumericOnlyKeyBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var validKeys = new[] { Keys.Back, Keys.D0, Keys.D1 };

    e.Handled = !validKeys.Contains((Keys)e.KeyChar);
}
```

Setting `e.Handled` to true / false indicates if the character should be accepted to the box or not.

You can read more about [KeyPressEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx?PHPSESSID=7c61ntavm1dmu84rl10kephll5) on MSDN.

**Note**

Keys.Delete should cover Keys.Delete, Keys.Backspace and other "Back" buttons.

Comment: Better this: `e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == Keys.D0) || (e.KeyChar == Keys.D1);`

Comment: @abatishchev -- haha, clever.  :-D

Comment: @abatischev, Don't forget the numpad. :)

Comment: You should also take care of backspace and delete

Comment: arrow keys? tab? what if they want to paste using Ctrl+V?

Comment: @adam0101: Try before ask ;) `KeyPress` will not be fired on pressing delete, arrows or tab. Yes, Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V will bot work but Cntrl+Ins/Shift+Ins will.

Comment: @adam0101, refactored a bit. You can now use Delete key, Backspace, 0 , 1 numpad 0 and 1.

Comment: Right-click the text box and select Paste.

Comment: @Hans, Actually one solution would be to use `protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)` and check for paste/copy messages. But then you would have to override the TextBox and do that. Another solution is to override the TextChanged event and just add a loop that checks each character and removes the incorrect ones. To make the example a bit simple, I wont add that though, there's enough information in this last comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you do want to show the numbers rather than a check or something but only want to allow 0 or 1 you could use a `NumericUpDown` control and set min to 0 max to 1 and step to 1.

If you do actually need a textbox I'd use Filip's answer but I'd set the `MaxLength` of it to 1 to avoid having to worry about 00, 11 or 01 or similar values.

Comment: +1 -- I personally think that this is the best answer, really. And if you want it as a string, well then use .ToString() -- And you're done. (and so little code, too!)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see the answer to this related question:

[C# Input validation for a Textbox: float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828546/c-input-validation-for-a-textbox-float)